# generating dynamic select box after form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im building an upload form where a user can upload a document along with details about the document such as its name etc. The issue that I am having is that when a user selects a category using a select I have to generate another select which then gives the user the option of choosing a sub category. see the following:-

```
 $(".department").change(function() {
    var url = "includes/get-categories.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#upload-modal").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data){
            //this is where the select is generated
            $(".sub").html(data); // show response from the php script.
            //The alert works but the above line does not
            alert("yeahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh boi");
       }
     });
```

Now this works like it should in that when the select is changed it generates another select from get-categories and gives the user another select box. But for some reason when a user submits the form and they are presented with a list of errors in the form (fields left blank etc) the select box will no longer be generated by selecting a category. I even tested the code with an alert which did work so im really confused as to why the following line doesnt work

```
$(".sub").html(data);
```

Here is my form which is pretty standard

```
echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='POST' autocomplete='off' id='upload-modal'>"; 
echo '<fieldset>';
echo '<legend>Please fill in all the fields below:- </legend>';

echo '<label for="docname">Document name</label>';
echo '<input class="block" type="text" name="docname" id="docname" value="'.$_POST['docname'].'" />';

echo '<label for="version">Version (if left blank it will be entered as 1.0)</label>';
echo '<input class="block" type="text" name="version" id="version" value="'.$_POST['version'].'" />';

//We need to now give a drop down for the admin to select a department


    try {
        $conn = new PDO(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT X FROM Y WHERE Z = :id');
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => A));
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

     // if the user is an admin we provide them with the admin link
            if($row['admin_level']=="super" ||     $row['admin_level']=="admin" && $row['department']=="Assurance" ){
                echo '<select id="department" class="block department" name="department">';
                echo '<option value="0">department...</option>';
                echo '<option value="policies">Policies</option>';
                echo '<option value="procedures">Procedures</option>';
                echo '</select>';                   
            } 

            echo '<p class="sub"></p>';
        }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }                   



echo '<label for="keywords">Enter keywords (seperate with ",")</label>';
echo '<textarea id="keywords block" name="keywords" rows="4" cols="50" value="'.$_POST['keywords'].'"></textarea> ';

echo '<label for="filename">Supported formats - .docx & .pdf</label>';
echo '<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" title="Supported formats - .docx and .pdf" />';

echo '<input class="submit-ie6" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="upload-modal-submit" />';

echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
```

Any help is most appeciated

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tool like Firebug and see why after the submit, this: $(".sub").html(data); does not work. The reason probably is because after you submit the form(with errors) the:

```
echo '<p class="sub"></p>';
```

is not there.

I would suggest the below:
Get your

```
<p class="sub"></p>
```

out of try{} and just use css like:

```
<p class="sub" style="display:none;"></p>
```

So all you have to do, is when the user selects a category, create the second select box and remove the display:none from the p like:

```
$(".sub").html(data);  
$(".sub").show();
```

Comment: Hi malix thanks for the response, I use firebug extensively and have already checked to see if the p tag was missing which its not. I also used firebug to check to see if the ajax request was being sent and again it has been sent so im pretty confused as to why its not working. Im starting to think that you have the right idea in a new approach

Comment: Try this solution and tell me what happens. Although my solution would be to just fill up the second select box with values and not create it from scratch.